# Part of sidebar drops below content at certain screensizes

Tags: html, css

I have experimented with different methods but have yet to find a way to keep parts of my sidebar from dropping below my main-post at certain screen-sizes.

(They are all supossed to drop below the content on mobile but NOT while the screen is still in PC/tablet size)

Is there any way to change them or put them into a container so that they stay on the left, without having to redo everything?

https://codepen.io/Pinchofginger/pen/ypzMvX

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 40.5em)" href="styletablet.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="body">

  <div class="maincontent">
    <div class="content">
      <article class="topcontent"> 
                <img class="mellemh" src="http://i1246.photobucket.com/albums/gg611/Rcoslive/tumblr_opglesDkzP1rfn5l1o1_540_zpsk1t1dhzo.jpg" alt="Kdog"/>

<!-- 1 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------> 
<div class=brødtekst><p>  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
        </div></div></div>

  </article>



<div class="sidemenu">
  <aside class="top-sidebar">
            <article>
              <h3> <a href="#">Plejefamilier og frivillige søges</a></h3>
    </article>
        </aside>

        <aside class="middle-sidebar">
          <article>
            <h3>Ugens kat</h3> <img src="billeder/katte/mathilde.jpg" alt="Mathilde">
            <p><a href="#">Mathilde</a></p>
                              </article></aside>

    <aside class="middle-sidebar">
      <article>
  <img src="billeder/ungkat/sailor.jpg" alt="Sailor" >
        <p> <a href="#">Sailor</a> </p>
                     </article></aside>

        <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
          <article>
<h3>Ugens killng</h3>
            <img src="billeder/killinger/mr.grey.jpg" alt="Mr.Grey" >
  <p><a href="#">Mr.Grey</p></a>
  <p>en herlig lille gut med fuld fart på!</p>

    </article>
</aside>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/******************************************************************/

/*                            RESET                               */

/*                        ______________                          */

/*meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/               v2.0 | 20110126*/

/*License: none (public domain)                                   */

/******************************************************************/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*******************************************************************/

/*                    GEN                                     */

/*******************************************************************/

/* Box-sizing = width or height + padding + border = reelle højde og bredde. */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/***********************************************************/

/*         Billeder! Img!    ******      Video!            */

/***********************************************************/
.mellemh {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 2px;;
  width: 55%;}

.sidemenu img { width: 40%; float: left; margin-right: 5px; }

/***********************************************************/

/*                       Tekst!                            */

/***********************************************************/
.sidemenu .b {font-weight: bold; color: orange;}
.content h1, h2, h3 {
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  }

.sidebar h1, h2, h3 {margin: 0 0 2% 0;}

  h1 {font-size: 1.5em; color: orange;}
  h2 {font-size: 1.3em;color: orange;}
  h3 {font-size: 1.1em;color: orange;}

  .brødtekst 
  {white-space: pre-line;}

/******************************************************************************/

/*                               SIDEBAR!                                       */

/******************************************************************************/

.top-sidebar {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1% 1% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.middle-sidebar {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
float: left;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1% 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 1% 1% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.bottom-sidebar {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
float: left;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
      padding: 0 1% 1% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

/******************************************************************************/

/*                   MAIN!          *****       BODY!                         */

/******************************************************************************/

body {
  background-color: grey;
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
  text-align: left;
}

.body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Alt er centreret*/
  width: 99%;
  clear: both;
}

/* Ikke nødvendigt, men godt at have "just in case"*/

.maincontent {
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;}



.topcontent {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
    padding: 3% 3% 3% 3%
}


/*  BIG SCREENS START HERE*******************/
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.5em) {

/* IMG!  ***************   VIDEO!    *************************************/

.sidemenu img { float: none; width: 70%; margin: 2 auto; }
.top-sidebar img {width: 70%;}

  .mellemh {
  padding: 10px 20px 0 2px;;
  width: 35%;}


/* MAIN! BODY! *********************************************************/

body {
  background-image: url("billeder/bgorange.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
  /* Base font size (14px)? 7%*/
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
  text-align: left;
}

.body { width: 90%;}

.maincontent {
   display: flex; flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 81%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.topcontent {
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */

  padding: 1% 3% 1%% 3%
}

.bottomcontent {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  padding: 1% 5% 3% 3%
}


/* SIDEBAR!***************************************************************/


        .top-sidebar {
          text-align: center;
              width: 18%;
          float: left;
          background-color: white;
          padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
          margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
          border-radius: 5px;
          /* pæne runde hjørner*/
          -moz-border-radius: 5px;
          /* Fox*/
          -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
          /* IE */
        }

        .middle-sidebar {
          text-align: center;
              width: 18%;
          float:left;
          background-color: white;
          padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
          margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
          border-radius: 5px;
          /* pæne runde hjørner*/
          -moz-border-radius: 5px;
          /* Fox*/
          -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
          /* IE */
        }

        .bottom-sidebar {
          text-align: center;
          width: 18%;
          float: left;
          background-color: white;
          padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
          margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
          border-radius: 5px;
          /* pæne runde hjørner*/
          -moz-border-radius: 5px;
          /* Fox*/
          -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
          /* IE */
        }

        .sidemenu p {color: grey;}
```

Comment: Hi. Did you think about using flexbox instead of float ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to redo everything to flexbox model, you can add a small fix:

```
.maincontent {
  /*your code here for this block*/
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
```

And the last sidebar block will not fall. It's nice as a temporary solution but I strongly recommend to use flexbox instead for this layout.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked.
Could you give me some tips on how I could turn this into a flexbox layout without having to redo everything?

Comment: @Ginger could you please mark my answer as a right one? =)

Comment: @Ginger surely, I can help. 

- remove all the floats (from the parts of sidebar and .maincontent)
- add #sidemenu display flex and flex-direction: column
- wrap #sidemenu and .maincontent into a div (with class="wrapper") for example, add to this div display flex and justify-content space-between. Also add to #sidemenu and .maincontent flex-shrink: 0

Comment: @Ginger https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties this article will be really helpful for you

Comment: Thank you so much dear. If you have the time, could you perhaps take a look at my code one final time, I cant quite seem to get the flex to work the way you suggested: https://codepen.io/Pinchofginger/pen/aELgXJ?editors=1100